# Invalid operation exception , C# XML Error

Tags: c#, xml, invalidoperationexception

Heyo, I am making a plugin for unity game(error below) so I am probably making this for my main plugin and read ranks. I dont know what is the error and I dont see any posts about this. This is my error  :

```
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Rank")]
public List<Rank> Ranks;
public void LoadDefaults()
{
    Ranks = new List<Rank>() {
    new Rank() { RankNumber = 0, GroupID = "Default" ,Messages = new List<Message>() { new Message("yo") , new Message("yo")}}
    };
}
public class Rank
{
    public Rank() { }

    public int RankNumber;
    public string GroupID;
    public List<Message> Messages;
}
public class Message
{
    public Message(string Rankmessage) { Rankmessage = RankMessage; }
    [XmlAttribute("RankMessage")]
    public string RankMessage;
}
```

Error:

```
[2/3/2017 7:47:23 PM] [Error] InvalidOperationException: RanksUnlocker.RanksUnlockerConfig+Message cannot be serialized because it does not have a default public constructor - System.Xml.Serialization.ReflectionHelper.CheckSerializableType (System.Type type, Boolean allowPrivateConstructors)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportClassMapping (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String defaultNamespace)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String defaultNamespace)
Rethrow as InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'RanksUnlocker.RanksUnlockerConfig+Message'.
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String defaultNamespace)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping (System.Type type, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String defaultNamespace)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportListMapping (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String defaultNamespace, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributes atts, Int32 nestingLevel)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportListMapping (System.Type type, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String defaultNamespace, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributes atts, Int32 nestingLevel)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.CreateMapMember (System.Type declaringType, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionMember rmember, System.String defaultNamespace)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportClassMapping (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String defaultNamespace)
Rethrow as InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting field 'Messages'.
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportClassMapping (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String defaultNamespace)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String defaultNamespace)
Rethrow as InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'RanksUnlocker.RanksUnlockerConfig+Rank'.
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String defaultNamespace)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping (System.Type type, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String defaultNamespace)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportListMapping (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String defaultNamespace, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributes atts, Int32 nestingLevel)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportListMapping (System.Type type, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String defaultNamespace, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributes atts, Int32 nestingLevel)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.CreateMapMember (System.Type declaringType, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionMember rmember, System.String defaultNamespace)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportClassMapping (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String defaultNamespace)
Rethrow as InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting field 'Ranks'.
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportClassMapping (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String defaultNamespace)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String defaultNamespace)
Rethrow as InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'RanksUnlocker.RanksUnlockerConfig'.
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String defaultNamespace)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping (System.Type type, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String defaultNamespace)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor (System.Type type, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeOverrides overrides, System.Type[] extraTypes, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String defaultNamespace)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor (System.Type type, System.Type[] extraTypes)
Rocket.Core.Assets.XMLFileAsset`1[RanksUnlocker.RanksUnlockerConfig]..ctor (System.String file, System.Type[] extraTypes, RanksUnlocker.RanksUnlockerConfig defaultInstance)
Rocket.Core.Plugins.RocketPlugin`1[RocketPluginConfiguration]..ctor ()
RanksUnlocker.RanksUnlocker..ctor ()
UnityEngine.GameObject:.ctor(String, Type[])
Rocket.Core.Plugins.RocketPluginManager:loadPlugins()
Rocket.Core.Plugins.RocketPluginManager:Start()
```

Comment: The error is self explanatory.  Your nested type `RanksUnlocker.RanksUnlockerConfig+Message` must have a public **parameterless** constructor.  See for instance [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2498243/3744182).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a constructor to the `Message` class.  It needs to be `public` and it needs to accept zero parameters.

The the existing constructor that you already have won't work for this because the XML serialization process doesn't know how to handle a constructor that takes a parameter.  You can keep your existing constructor too, just add a new one that doesn't take a parameter.

Comment: Thanks! i've added public Message() { }